# How to write sql query for computing quartile every year

Tags: sql-server

I have tried some query using NTILE but it is not working for calculating quartile every year. SQL query is below.

```
select distinct datepart(Week,startingdate) as Week,datepart(year,startingdate) as years,sum(users+isnull(tbl_MobileGoogleAnalyticsData.M_Users,0)) as users 
into #googleanalyticsUsers  
from tbl_GoogleAnalyticsData 
left join tbl_MobileGoogleAnalyticsData on tbl_GoogleAnalyticsData.actualdate=tbl_MobileGoogleAnalyticsData.M_ActualDate   
group by datepart(Week,startingdate) ,datepart(year,startingdate)

select  distinct Week, years,users  from #googleanalyticsUsers order by years asc

select distinct week,NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY years DESC) AS Quartile,years 
from #googleanalyticsUsers 
order by years asc
```

Problem is I have data in week wise, so I need to sum every 13th week of the year (means quarterly) and this sum should happens every year. How to do please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your quarter a full 13 week set regardless of what day Jan 1 falls on?  In that case (`52*7=364`), one of your quarters will have 1 or 2 (leap year) days extra.  You will also have more than 52 weeks.  You may benefit from using NTILE over the actual day, rather than the start of the week.

In any case, you can use `NTILE` and `Parition by` and `Order by` to order your weeks and group them into quarters.

Here is an example with a sequence of dates

```
;With SequenceNum as
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By C1.Ordinal_Position) Adder
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
),
DateList as
(
    Select DateAdd (D, Adder-1, '1/1/2000') as OneDate
    From SequenceNum
    Where Adder < (365 *10) /* only get 10 years of data*/
)
Select 
    OneDate, 
    DatePart (Year, OneDate) YearNum, 
    DatePart (Week, OneDate) WeekNum,
    NTILE(4) Over (Partition By DatePart (Year, OneDate) Order By DatePart (Week, OneDate)) TileValue
From DateList
```